# Loop through list for curl requests in bash

Tags: bash, loops, curl

I have a bash script that sends a curl request and displays the response.

```
    #!/bin/bash

token=$(curl -k -X GET \
'https://v.mytesting.io/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user1&password=123' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic 12345678' \
-H 'Host: v.mytesting.io.io')
v=$( jq -r ".access_token" <<<"$token" )

ts=$(curl -k -X POST \
https://timeseries.mytimeseries.io/v5/time_series/query \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$v" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Host: timeseries.mytimeseries.io' \
-H 'tenant: 123-123-123' \
-d '{"operation" : "raw","responseFormat" : "kairosDB","startTime": "1d-ago","stopTime": "now","tagList" : [ {"tagId" : "V.S.23164117.AVG.10M"}]}')


p=$(jq '.queries[].sample_size, .queries[].results[].name' <<<"$ts")
echo "$p"
```

My current output is just a value and the name of the tagId.
My query only allows for 1 tagId  ( you can see above )

I want to be able to set a list of tagId's.
Then when I run this script it should loop through the list of tagId's and execute the curl request replacing the V.S.23164117.AVG.10M with each value 
in the list.
Then output the entire list of results into a file.

list would be like so - (I would love to be able to enter this list into a seperate file and the bash script calls that file. Sometimes this list can be a few hundred lines.

- V.S.23164117.AVG.10M
- V.S.23164118.AVG.10M
- V.S.23164119.AVG.10M
- V.S.23164115.AVG.10M
- V.S.23164114.AVG.10M

output would like look so.

- value tagId
- value tagId
- value tagId
- 100 V.S.23164117.AVG.10M
- etc..

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over list of tags using a small script. I'm not 100% clean of the output format. You can change the 'echo' to match the required format.

Note minor change to quotes to allow variable expansion in the body.

The tags will be stored in a file, for examples, tags.txt

```
V.S.23164117.AVG.10M
V.S.23164118.AVG.10M
V.S.23164119.AVG.10M
```

And the script will be use the file

```
#! /bin/bash
   # Use user defined list of tags
tags=tags.txt
token=$(curl -k -X GET \
'https://v.mytesting.io/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user1&password=123' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic 12345678' \
-H 'Host: v.mytesting.io.io')
v=$( jq -r ".access_token" <<<"$token" )

for tag in $(<$tags) ; do
ts=$(curl -k -X POST \
https://timeseries.mytimeseries.io/v5/time_series/query \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$v" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Host: timeseries.mytimeseries.io' \
-H 'tenant: 123-123-123' \
-d '{"operation" : "raw","responseFormat" : "kairosDB","startTime": "1d-ago","stopTime": "now","tagList" : [ {"tagId" : "'"$tag"'"}]}')

    p=$(jq '.queries[].sample_size, .queries[].results[].name' <<<"$ts")

    echo "$tag $p"
done
```

Comment: how would i enter the list of tags ? like this tags=$123,$234

Comment: @TammiSantiago Slightly changed the code to address this question

Comment: thanks. i created the file. but i just receive this error when I run it now. line 13: tags: No such file or directory

Comment: @TammiSantiago Typo in line 13 fixed (`tags` replaced with `$tags`). I think you already figured this one out